# Error: contract runner does not support sending transactions (operation="sendTransaction", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=6.6.3)

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, defi

I got this error when tried to deposit eth to weth contact from mainnet, using hardhat forking, does anyone know how to fix this error ?

```
const { getNamedAccounts, ethers, } = require("hardhat")

const AMOUNT = ethers.parseEther("0.02")

async function getWeth() {
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    const iWeth = await ethers.getContractAt(
        "IWeth",
        "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2",
        deployer,
    )
    const tx = await iWeth.deposit({ value: AMOUNT })
    await tx.wait(1)
    const wethBalance = await iWeth.balanceOf(deployer)
    console.log(`Got ${wethBalance.toString()} WETH`)
}

module.exports = { getWeth }
```

I console.log contract got from getContractAt(), It's shown like this, please help

```
Contract {
  target: '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2',
  interface: Interface {
    fragments: [
      [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment]
    ],
    deploy: ConstructorFragment {
      type: 'constructor',
      inputs: [],
      payable: false,
      gas: null
    },
    fallback: null,
    receive: false
  },
  runner: '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266',
  filters: {},
  fallback: null,
  [Symbol(_ethersInternal_contract)]: {}
}
```

```
/home/sonhd/blockchain/hardhat-defi-fcc/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/utils/errors.ts:677
            error = new Error(message);
                    ^
Error: contract runner does not support sending transactions (operation="sendTransaction", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=6.6.4)
    at makeError (.../hardhat-defi-fcc/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/utils/errors.ts:677:21)
    at assert (.../hardhat-defi-fcc/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/utils/errors.ts:694:25)
    at send (.../hardhat-defi-fcc/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:288:15)
    at Proxy.deposit (.../hardhat-defi-fcc/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:330:22)
    at getWeth (.../hardhat-defi-fcc/scripts/getWeth.js:13:28)
    at main (.../hardhat-defi-fcc/scripts/aaveBorrow.js:3:2)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Hardhat package.json config

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@chainlink/contracts": "^0.6.1",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers": "^3.0.4",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "npm:hardhat-deploy-ethers",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan": "^3.1.7",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.6",
    "chai": "^4.3.7",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "ethereum-waffle": "^4.0.10",
    "ethers": "^6.6.4",
    "hardhat": "^2.17.0",
    "hardhat-contract-sizer": "^2.10.0",
    "hardhat-deploy": "^0.11.34",
    "hardhat-gas-reporter": "^1.0.9",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "prettier-plugin-solidity": "^1.1.3",
    "solhint": "^3.4.1",
    "solidity-coverage": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

And the contract could be found at [hardhat-defi-fcc/tree/main/contracts/interfaces](https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/hardhat-defi-fcc/tree/main/contracts/interfaces)

Answer (score 3):

You just need to get a signer by `const signer = await ethers.provider.getSigner()`
and then, pass this signer to sign transaction in the `ethers.getContractAt()` function rather than `deployer` in your case.

Also remember, just use `ethers.parseEther("0.02")` with updated versions of ethers rather than "ethers.utils.parseEther("0.02")".

```
const { getNamedAccounts, ethers } = require("hardhat")

const AMOUNT = ethers.parseEther("0.02")

async function getWeth() {
   const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()

   const signer = await ethers.provider.getSigner()

   const iWeth = await ethers.getContractAt(
       "IWeth",
       "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2",
       signer,
   )

   const tx = await iWeth.deposit({ value: AMOUNT })
   await tx.wait(1)
   const wethBalance = await iWeth.balanceOf(deployer)
   console.log(`Got ${wethBalance.toString()} WETH.`)
}

module.exports = { getWeth }
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I found a solution that worked  based on [Malik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76137839/error-contract-runner-does-not-support-calling-operation-call-code-unsuppor/76540964#76540964)

In summary, we need a `signer` to change the state of the contract (as we are using the `deposit()` function). To achieve this, I used `ethers.provider.getSigner()`.

I also used `getTheAbi()` to obtain the ABI of the contract.

I believe there might be a better way to get the abi because we already have contract by using `ethers.getContractAt()`, but I don't know.
Hopefully, someone can provide a more efficient approach."

```
const fs = require("fs")
const path = require("path")

const getTheAbi = () => {
    try {
        const dir = path.resolve(
            __dirname,
            "../artifacts/contracts/interfaces/IWeth.sol/IWeth.json", // hardhat build dir
        )
        const file = fs.readFileSync(dir, "utf8")
        const json = JSON.parse(file)
        return json.abi

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`e`, e)
    }
}

const { getNamedAccounts, ethers } = require("hardhat")
const AMOUNT = ethers.parseEther("0.02")

async function getWeth() {
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    const abi = getTheAbi()
    const signer = await ethers.provider.getSigner()
    const newcontract = new ethers.Contract(
        "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2",
        abi,
        signer,
    )
    const tx = await newcontract.deposit({ value: AMOUNT })
    await tx.wait(1)
    const wethBalance = await newcontract.balanceOf(deployer)
    console.log(`Got ${wethBalance.toString()} WETH`)
}

module.exports = { getWeth }
```

Answer (score 2):

Although slightly unrelated, I will leave my solution here for anyone who finds themselves here with a similar issue.

I was trying to use an Ethereum address in my connect function when I actually needed an `ethers.signer` object. Below is the incorrect code:

```
[deployer, recipient, ...otherAccounts] = await ethers.getSigners();
await token.connect(accounts[0].address).mint("1000000000000000000000");
```

and the correct code:

````
[deployer, recipient, ...otherAccounts] = await ethers.getSigners();
await token.connect(accounts[0]).mint("1000000000000000000000");```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const { expect } = require("chai");


const contractAddress = "0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3";

describe("Access Storage Test", function () {
    
    // variables accessible throughout the test
    let contractInstance, signer1, signer1Address

    beforeEach("setup", async () => {
   
        // if hardhat or local dev is used leave it empty, but 
        // in hardhat.config
        provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider();

        // if a 3rd party service is used.
        provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(`https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/${process.env.ALCHEMY_SEPOLIA_API_KEY}`);

        signer1= new ethers.Wallet(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_ONE, provider);
        signer1Address = await signer1.getAddress();

        const contractArtifact = await artifacts.readArtifact("contractName");
        const abi = contractArtifact .abi;
        try {
            contractInstance = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, provider);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error creating contract instance:", error);
        }
})

desribe('whatever', function() {
it('execute deposit', async () => {
   const depositTx = await contractInstance.connect(signer1).deposit({value: ethers.parseEther("0.05")})
})
```

I believe this is a better way to get contract's abi and utilize different signers if needed as per ethers v6.
I hope I helped a bit.
Don't forget to set paths in hardhat.config.js:

```
paths: {
    sources: "./contracts", 
    artifacts: "./artifacts", 
    cache: "./cache"
  },
```