# Encountering an error with getContractAt using hardhat-ethers and ethers v.6.6.7

Tags: ethers.js, javascript, hardhat

I am doing a tutorial on youtube, and I can't figure out why I am getting an error code by running `yarn hardhat run scripts/aaveBorrow.js`:

```
Error: contract runner does not support calling (operation="call", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=6.6.7)
at makeError (C:\Users\mitro\OneDrive - 365education\Documents\a_progra\32_hrs_blockchain\hardhat-defi\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:677:21)
at assert (C:\Users\mitro\OneDrive - 365education\Documents\a_progra\32_hrs_blockchain\hardhat-defi\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:694:25)
at staticCallResult (C:\Users\mitro\OneDrive - 365education\Documents\a_progra\32_hrs_blockchain\hardhat-defi\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:316:15)
at staticCall (C:\Users\mitro\OneDrive - 365education\Documents\a_progra\32_hrs_blockchain\hardhat-defi\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:289:30)
at Proxy.getLendingPool (C:\Users\mitro\OneDrive - 365education\Documents\a_progra\32_hrs_blockchain\hardhat-defi\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:337:47)
at getLendingPool (C:\Users\mitro\OneDrive - 365education\Documents\a_progra\32_hrs_blockchain\hardhat-defi\scripts\aaveBorrow.js:17:65)
at main (C:\Users\mitro\OneDrive - 365education\Documents\a_progra\32_hrs_blockchain\hardhat-defi\scripts\aaveBorrow.js:7:23) {
  code: 'UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION',
  operation: 'call'
}
```

I am working with `ethers v6.6.7`, and hardhat. The `hardhat-ethers version is 1.0.1`
Here are my two files inside of the scripts folder:

**aaveBorrow.js:**

```
const { getWeth } = require("../scripts/getWeth");

const main = async () => {
  await getWeth();
  const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts();
  const lendingPool = await getLendingPool(deployer);
  console.log(`LendingPool address: ${lendingPool.address}`);
};

const getLendingPool = async (account) => {
  const lendingPoolAddressesProvider = await ethers.getContractAt(
    "ILendingPoolAddressesProvider",
    "0xB53C1a33016B2DC2fF3653530bfF1848a515c8c5",
    account,
  );
  const lendingPoolAddress = await lendingPoolAddressesProvider.getLendingPool();

  const lendingPool = await ethers.getContractAt(
    "ILendingPool",
    lendingPoolAddress,
    account,
  );
  return lendingPool;
};

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error:", error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

**getWeth.js:**

```
const path = require("path");

const getTheAbi = () => {
  try {
    const dir = path.resolve(
      __dirname,
      "../artifacts/contracts/interfaces/IWeth.sol/IWeth.json", // hardhat build dir
    );
    const file = fs.readFileSync(dir, "utf8");
    const json = JSON.parse(file);
    return json.abi;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`Error: ${e}`);
  }
};

// everything above comes from stackexchange, it solve the problem: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/152508/error-contract-runner-does-not-support-sending-transactions-operation-sendtra

const { getNamedAccounts, ethers } = require("hardhat");
const AMOUNT = ethers.parseEther("0.02");

async function getWeth() {
  const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts();
  const abi = getTheAbi();
  const signer = await ethers.provider.getSigner();
  const newcontract = new ethers.Contract(
    "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2",
    abi,
    signer,
  );
  const tx = await newcontract.deposit({ value: AMOUNT });
  await tx.wait(1);
  const wethBalance = await newcontract.balanceOf(deployer);
  console.log(`Got ${wethBalance.toString()} WETH`);
}

module.exports = { getWeth };
```

If you need any other file, just teel me :)

Comment: by the way, i am working with aave to get the contract

Comment: Did you find the solution? having same issue